# How to modify AJAX Control Toolkit Twitter templates?

Tags: ajax, twitter, toolkit

can anyone reference an article on **how to define/modify Ajax Control Toolkit Twitter control templates** (LayoutTemplate, StatusTemplate, AlternatingStatusTemplate and EmptyDataTemplate)?

Thanks!